# Javascript classes & event handlers

Tags: javascript, oop, events

I have a problem with this javascript code:

```
function MyClass() {
    var id_nr = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 999999);
    this.button_id = 'button_' + id_nr;
}


MyClass.prototype = {
    createButton: function() {
        var msg = 'Button \'' + this.button_id + '\' was clicked';

        var my_button = (
            '<input type="button" id="'
            + this.button_id
            + '" value="Click Me" /\>'
        );

        document.body.innerHTML += '<div>' + my_button + '</div>';
        document.getElementById(this.button_id).onclick = function() { alert(msg); }
    }
};


window.onload = function() {
    var s = new MyClass();
    s.createButton();
};
```

Yes, this current code works fine. But the problem appears when I add more than one MyClass objects:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var s = new MyClass();
    s.createButton();

    var w = new MyClass();
    w.createButton();

    /* ...and many other buttons */

};
```

For some reason the ***onclick*** event will be triggered only if I click the button that was created last. And I don't know why.

One workaround could be something like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:doSomeThing();" />
```

But unfortunately this is not the proper solution right row, because my goal is that the onclik event should be able to call another class methods as well. (Those methods are not created yet).

How can I make this code work properly? Any kind of a help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `innerHTML` the contents get stripped from the DOM and then readded and parsed again, breaking any past event listener that you might have added.

If you want to do it in vanilla JS, consider using [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild) and, also, I would suggest [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener?redirect=no). Your code would then look like so:

```
var my_button   = document.createElement('input');
my_button.type  = 'button';
my_button.id    = this.button_id;
my_button.value = 'Click me';

document.body.appendChild(my_button);
my_button.addEventListener('click', function () { alert (msg) });
```

<kbd>[**Working example with vanilla Javascript**](http://jsbin.com/ahosum/1/edit)</kbd>

If you are up to using some jQuery, this would be so much easier to implement. Your method would look something like:

```
var my_button = $('<input>')
                .prop('type', 'button')
                .prop('id',   this.button_id)
                .val('Click Me')
                .on('click', function () { alert(msg) } );

$('body').append(my_button)
```

<kbd>[**Working example with jQuery**](http://jsbin.com/ahosum/3/edit)</kbd>

Or you could perhaps use the [`jQuery.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data) method to delegate an event handler to all subsequent instances of your buttons.

<kbd>[**Working example with delegated event handler**](http://jsbin.com/ahosum/6/edit)</kbd>

Comment: I've already tried jQuery but same error remains. Also, ID-s cannot be the reason in here: each input element will have a unique ID in this code.

Comment: I also added some working examples in JSBin, check them out! :)

Comment: The **appendChild** trick actually worked! Thank you! First I thought it has the same effect as using innerHTML. So I never bothered to use it.

Comment: It is just because the innerHTML property completely reparses the HTML, and your event handlers disappear!

Answer (score 0):

The use of innerHTML here seems to break the event listener "onclick".

You can avoid this by using the document.createElement method to create your html element :

```
var but = document.createElement("input");
but.type = "button";
but.id = this.button_id;
but.value = "Click me";

document.body.appendChild(but);
```

Personaly, I prefer use jQuery for manipulating the DOM tree element, as it offer really powerfull tools for this.